# Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminDao';

Tags: java, mysql, spring

hola que tal tengo este error:

> Error creating bean with name 'adminServiceDAOImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'adminDao';

```
public interface AdminDao {

    public boolean save(Admin admin);
    public List<Admin> findAll();
    public Admin findById(int id);
    public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre);
    public boolean update(Admin admin);
    public boolean delete(int idAd);
    public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins);
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class AdminDaoImpl implements AdminDao{

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(Admin admin) {
//      MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
//      paramMap.addValue("nombre", admin.getNombre());
//      paramMap.addValue("cargo", admin.getCargo());
//      paramMap.addValue("fechaCreacion", admin.getFechaCreacion());

        BeanPropertySqlParameterSource paramMap = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(admin);

        return jdbcTemplate.
                update("insert into Admin (nombre, cargo, fechaCreacion) values (:nombre, :cargo, :fechaCreacion)", paramMap) == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Admin", new RowMapper<Admin>() {

            @Override
            public Admin mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Admin admin = new Admin();

                admin.setIdAd(rs.getInt("idAd"));
                admin.setCargo(rs.getString("cargo"));
                admin.setFechaCreacion(rs.getTimestamp("fechaCreacion"));
                admin.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));

                return admin;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Admin findById(int id) {
//      return (Admin) jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Admin where idAd=:idAd", 
//              new MapSqlParameterSource("idAd", id) ,new AdminRowMapper());

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from Admin where idAd=:idAd", 
                new MapSqlParameterSource("idAd", id), new AdminRowMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Admin where nombre like :nombre", 
                new MapSqlParameterSource("nombre", "%" + nombre + "%"), new AdminRowMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Admin admin) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("update Admin set nombre=:nombre, cargo=:cargo, fechaCreacion=:fechaCreacion where idAd=:idAd", 
                new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(admin)) == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int idAd) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("delete from Admin where idAd=:idAd", new MapSqlParameterSource("idAd", idAd)) == 1;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins) {
        SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(admins.toArray());

        return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into Admin (idAd, nombre, cargo, fechaCreacion) values (:idAd, :nombre, :cargo, :fechaCreacion)", 
                batchArgs);
    }



}
```

---

```
public interface AdminService {

    public boolean save(Admin admin);
    public List<Admin> findAll();
    public Admin findById(int id);
    public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre);
    public boolean update(Admin admin);
    public boolean delete(int idAd);
    public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins);
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(Admin admin);

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService  {

    @Autowired
    private AdminDao adminDao;

    @Override
    public boolean save(Admin admin){
        admin.setFechaCreacion(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

        return adminDao.save(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findAll() {
            return adminDao.findAll();
        }


    @Override
    public Admin findById(int id) {
        return adminDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre) {

        return adminDao.findByNombre(nombre);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.update(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int idAd) {
        return adminDao.delete(idAd);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins) {
        return adminDao.saveAll(admins);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(Admin admin) {
        if (admin.getIdAd() == 0) {
            // Insert
            admin.setFechaCreacion(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            return adminDao.save(admin);
        }
        else{
            // Update
            return adminDao.update(admin);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminS;

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String showAdmin(Model model, 
            @ModelAttribute("resultado") String resultado) {

        List<Admin> admins = adminS.findAll();

        Admin admin = new Admin();
        model.addAttribute("admin", admin);
        model.addAttribute("resultado", resultado);
        model.addAttribute("admins", admins);

        return "admin";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleAdmin(@ModelAttribute("admin") Admin adminForm, 
            Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {


        if (adminS.saveOrUpdate(adminForm)) {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", "Cambios realizados con éxito");
        }
        else{
            ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", "Error al realizar los cambios");
        }

        return "redirect:/admin";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/admin/{idAd}/update")
    public String showUpdate(Model model,
            @PathVariable("idAd") int id) {


        Admin admin = adminS.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("admin", admin);

        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/{idAd}/delete")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("idAd") int idAd,
            RedirectAttributes ra) {

        if (adminS.delete(idAd)) {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", "Cambios realizados con éxito");
        } 
        else {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", "Error al aplicar cambios");
        }
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
```

dispatcher.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>


<context:component-scan base-package="org.proyecto.spring.*"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ZS</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener> 
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener> 

<context-param> 
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
<param-value>           
      /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml 
</param-value> 
</context-param> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el proyecto? Esta un poco difícil encontrar el error.

Answer (score 1):

No sabe cómo inicializar AdminDao ya que no hay ninguna clase como tal registrada como componente. La que tienes registrada se llama AdminDaoImpl y para que te la coja desde el servicio tienes que cambiar la línea @Component de AdminDaoImpl por lo siguiente:

```
@Named("adminDao")
```

Otra opción es añadirle la siguiente anotación a la propiedad AdminDao del servicio:

```
@Qualifier("adminDaoImpl")
```